# Why are sound files always larger in size than an image file?

Tags: file

I am making 2D games. I noticed that PNG files are always much smaller in size than a second-long sound effect file. Why are sound files always larger in size than an image file?

Comment: That depends on the quality or compression of either files

Comment: I think you're comparing apples and oranges...

Answer (score 0):

Images and audio represent different types of data so it's difficult to compare them directly, it's a bit like comparing apples and orange.

However, the main reason that audio files are *normally* larger than static images is because audio files have an extra dimension, time, and therefore there is more overall data to represent. If you add time as a dimension to an image, you get video, which even without audio is much larger than an audio file.

Audio files aren't always larger than images though. Compression is the key factor, some image files are actually quite large if they're uncompressed and have a large color range (like HDR). An RAW uncompressed 2048*2048 image with 40-bits of color per pixel *could* take up to 168MB of space. Most songs you'd listen to would take up far less space than that, because MP3/AAC files are compressed.

The reverse case can also be true. If the song file was in WAV format, then a 4 minute song would be around 40MB. And that 2048*2048 image, using a compressed lossy format like WebP, might only take up 600KB.

But, assuming a reasonable compression with both, a standard large image compressed to 600KB, is going to be smaller than your average compressed song, which even at a lower quality is around 1MB per minute.

Answer (score -2):

Sound is portrayed different than images.

Where an image is a large grid of colored pixels, sound is recorded through soundwaves, which can differ from high-low pitches, loud/soft sound, tone, frequency, and bit depth. And that's a lot of data you hear in one second.

Perhaps this source might explain it in more depth: https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/audio-file-size#what-is-a-digital-audio-file

Comment: this is literally the opposite of how it works. Pixels have "more colour" than sound samples.

Comment: I think there's a good analogy to be made here between the way we digitize images by dividing space into a regular grid of samples and recording a colour intensity for each (RGB) channel at each sample site, versus the  way we digitize sound by dividing time into a regular ruler of samples and recording a pressure intensity for each (LR) channel at each sample moment. To improve this answer though, it would help to show the full accounting of bits per second / per pixel. Then of course compression algorithms complicate things further...